# permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory

Tags: octopress

I want to download and set octopress, and I follow the hint and type:

```
$cd octopress
$gem install bundler
```

then it shows that:

> "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.

What does it mean? I don't know how to write permissions for it. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question lack some basic information, I would say ;) For this kind of problem you should include at least your OS (I guess you are on mac os because of the `/Library` directory)

What the error says is that, as a normal user, you cannot write in the `/Library` directory, which is a system directory (and as such require administrator privilege).

From [what I read](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528), there is no `root` account on mac os by default, but maybe you can use `sudo` to issue a command with temporary privilege: try

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

and see if it works (it should prompt you from your password).

Otherwise, you can certainly install the program locally (in your `$HOME`), but as I never used mac os I can't really help you here. If the above does not work, I suggest you rephrase your question as "using gem on mac os", or something similar.